# How to avoid long constructors for simple groups of some values?

Tags: c++, constructor, struct, grouping, shortcut

I want to group some values, for example in a `struct`,  and easily set them when creating an object.

```
struct structure
{
    char letter;
    int number;
    float decimal;
};

structure object('c', 42, 12.3); // this doesn't work
```

I know that I could manually write a constructor like this.

```
struct structure
{
    structure(char letter, int number, float decimal) : letter(letter), number(number), decimal(decimal) {}
    char letter;
    int number;
    float decimal;
};

structure object('c', 42, 12.3); // this of course do work
```

But doing so is annoying since you have to mention each member twice and triple. But I just want to group some values...

Would I have only three of five values I would make use of `std::pair` and nest these.

```
typedef structure pair<char, pair<number, decimal>>;

structure object(make_pair('c', make_pair(42, 12.3)));
```

But for some more values it becomes really confusing to fetch the right values using `.first` and `.second`. In reality I want to group five values. Using nested pairs for that seems a bit hacky.

Is there a constructor for setting all members or something similar? What alternatives do I have to simply group some values without writing a constructor for them?

Comment: `structure object = {'c', 42, 12.3};` should work. Also, a `std::tuple` is preferable to nested `std::pair`s with more than two values.

Comment: Check [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple), it's `std::pair` on steroids.

Comment: Do you only hold primitive types, or similar aggregates of same?

Comment: For now it's only about primitive types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you could use [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple), which is basically a collection of values with different types:

```
std::tuple<char, int, float> object('c', 42, 12.3f);
```

You can access the elements using [`std::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get). For example, to access the `char`, you would use `std::get<0>(object)`.

Second, if you use the struct, you could initialize it with aggregate initialization:

```
structure object = {'c', 42, 12.3f};
// or even
structure object{'c', 42, 12.3f};
```

Comment: @sharethis For Visual C++, I'm afraid aggregate initialization is only available on Visual Studio 2012 Update 2. This hasn't been launched yet, but there is a Community Tech Preview (CTP), which is not meant for production code.

Comment: The first version `structure object = {'c', 42, 12.3f};` has worked since the stone age (or K&R C, whichever came first).

Comment: @bopersson so long as you do not break pod rules: which is the case here.